# jQuery scroll function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, scroll

I have this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(".splash").is(":visible")) {
        $(".site").css({"opacity":"0"});
        }
    });

$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(window).off("scroll"); 
    $(".splash").slideUp("800", function() {
      $("html, body").animate({"scrollTop":"0px"},100);
      $(".site").delay(100).animate({"opacity":"1.0"},800);
    });
})
```

I use this to pass from splash page to home in animation way. But when I'm in home page the scroll is still off and I need it to make a change in hte header. I use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var sT = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (sT >= 200) {
            $('header').addClass('scroll-header')
        } else {
            $('header').removeClass('scroll-header')
        }
    });
});
```

This two parts fight together!! How can I put on scroll after splash page to go out? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "fight together"?

Comment: @SachiDangalla hi! the first add (window).off("scroll") - after the animation the window still be off and the (window).scroll(function() of the header doesn't work

Comment: `$(window).off("scroll")` will remove all `scroll` event listeners from `$(window)`. It's probably better to use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) for the splash scroll event.

Comment: yes this it's a good idea! How i can write like $(window).scroll(function() { $(this).one('scroll', function() { code } exactly?

Comment: Hi have try this:
$(window).ready(function(){
$(this).one('scroll', function() { 
$(window).off("scroll"); 
$(".splash").slideUp("800", function() {
$("html, body").animate({"scrollTop":"0px"},100);
$(".site").delay(100).animate({"opacity":"1.0"},800);
});
})
});
But still not work

Comment: @SachiDangalla maybe i have understand the problem, the page don't reload after scroll so scroll it's not active. Do you know what i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i have try to not use scroll off, and change with a simple

```
.show_splash{position: fixed;}
```

In this way finely work!!!